# MacBook not out-putting sound to Bluetooth devices

Tags: macos, bluetooth

I have a MacBook running macOS Sierra which has been successfully connected to my Logitech Bluetooth audio device.  Recently it stopped working.  Specifically, in sys-prefs/sound it won't select the device.  In other words, the Bluetooth connection is made, but it won't set as a sound device.  I checked this with other Bluetooth sound devices from other manufacturers, so I believe it's a general Bluetooth audio issue.

Does anybody have any insight into this?

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't specify what you've tried to resolve this. Have you tried resetting things (or unpairing) and pairing again?

- On the MacBook go to System Preferences > Bluetooth and right-click on the Logitech device and select Remove
- On the Logitech device, follow the instructions on how to reset it
- Now go through the process of pairing them again

Comment: No I've done all the obvious things like rebooting, resetting the bluetooth, disconnecting, reconnecting, trashing bluetooth profile, resetting pram, testing against other bluetooth devices..

i wouldn't add to the question-base if i didn't believe it was a hard problem that i'd already googled for hours and tried all basic trial-and-error responses.

Comment: Glad to hear you wouldn't add to the question base unless you thought it was a _hard problem_, but there's no way for us to *know* that or to second guess what you've already trie, or what may be _obvious_ to you? For example: (1) have you also tried resetting the SMC? (2) Tested your Logitech device with another computer or phone/tablet? (3) Booted into Safe Mode and tried connecting?

Comment: the only thing i haven't done is try Safe Mode.  I'm not confident I'd know how to approach that..  just validate THAT it works in safe mode?  Can you describe that approach?

Comment: To boot into Safe Mode press and hold the Shift key while your Mac boots. Let go when you see the Apple logo and progress bar. It will take a little longer to boot, but when it's finished try using your Logitech device again and report back. To exit Safe Mode you just need to restart your computer.

Comment: I did that.  Unfortunately I'm at the apple store and didn't bring my bluetooth device.  But there is an AppleTV device that comes up under sound options.  Not sure if its bluetooth or wifi.  But the behavior in normal mode is 1) click device 2) active-device snaps back to previous device.  When I go into safe-mode, the ONLY sound-device listed is that AppleTV.  Now, it stays selected.  However, there are no other sound devices for it to snap back to.  So I'll have to try this again when I get home.  But again, assuming it works in Safe-Mode, where do I go from there..

Comment: Well, if it works fine in Safe Mode this eliminates the possibility of a hardware problem and means you can focus on troubleshooting 3rd party software related issues. Basically, we want it to work in Safe Mode. If not, we've narrowed it down to an issue with macOS Sierra (e.g. a corrupted file) or a hardware issue with the MacBook. So, if it works in Safe Mode we tackle 3rd party software. If it doesn't work in Safe Mode the next step would be to run Apple Diagnostics to eliminate a hardware problem. If that passes, we focus on macOS Sierra.

Comment: I took it to the apple-store and they mimicked a test OS on my hardware and it connected to a bluetooth speaker as a sound output.  So we deduced it is the OS (or software).  His solution was to repartition the disk and install a fresh OS.  Do you recommend any less "nuclear" options?